# Remove "default site" from MSM installation?

Tags: multi-site-manager

Is it possible to remove the "default site" from a MSM installation and then remove the MSM plugin, thereby creating a stand alone from the second site?

I'm running EE 2.7.2 with Multiple Site Manager

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to duplicate the entire MSM installation, set site #2 as the default, then delete Site #1.

I wrote an article about this process while doing it in EE1, so while some of the specifics will be different the overall process would be the same for EE2:

http://www.train-ee.com/courseware/free-tutorials/comments/splitting-a-site-out-of-an-ee-msm-installation

Comment: This is pretty much the way to do it. I just made an MSM site (site_id=2) the default one. Took 2 hours to backup, setup local, modify, test and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you're going to run into a bunch of problems.

I'd set up two separate installs and migrate the data using [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab).

Good luck!